# Angular app auth-free development process

Tags: angular, development-environment

I have an Angular app that is used for administrative purposes only, thus it has only login page that doesn't require user's authentication.

I'm looking for a way of specifying conditions where I can bypass login in dev mode to work with inner app structure that doesn't require data from the server. Also, I would like to provide my app with some dummy data to fill some tables to see the work and I want it to be conditionally imported i.e. I don't want to make my App huge with data that is not being used in prod mode.

Environment variable as it is isn't suitable for this case since it would contain too many data which I like to spread across files to make it better readable.

Answer (score 1):

So, what you want to do is use mock data.  In a perfect world, all your api calls will have mock json responses.  When you are in a development environment, all your API calls would return those mock JSON responses that replicate what your actual backend server might return.  Then you can navigate the app in 'dev' mode without requiring any backend support and works completely offline.

It's farly common to have a folder for mocks in a project, and json files take up very little space if your concern is having data that just wont be used in production.

EDIT: another option is creating your own fake endpoints using [JSON server](https://medium.com/@kaustubhtalathi/mock-data-for-angular-5-applications-with-json-server-part-1-d377eced223b), which will not add unused data to your project